# Adding a vector to params in YAML header

Tags: r, parameters, yaml, tidyverse

I'm trying to add a vector of school names to the YAML header without typing all 109 schools. I tried using `unique(nsc20.1$school)` but the document will not render.

title: "National Student Clearinghouse, 2012-2020"

subtitle: "State of College Report"

author: "Name"

date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%F')`"

output: hrbrthemes::ipsum_pdf

params:

school: !r c("Henderson High School", "Montgomery High School",...107 more schools)

**Is there a way to pass a vector of schools to params without typing all 109 school names?**